# SSH commands stopped working after updating Magento to 2.4.0

Tags: magento2.4.0

After updating Magento to `2.4.0`, When doing any SSH command, it shows `Constant name is expected`.

I found the issue is coming from the file `vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Constant.php.`

So I added a line `print_r($data);exit;` in the following if condition
`if (!isset($data['value']) || !defined($data['value'])`.

Then when I do Magento SSH commands, it showing the following error:

```php
Array
(
  [name] => code
  [value] => Magento\Braintree\Model\Ui\ConfigProvider::CODE
)
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are not using PayPal_Braintree try disabling the module.

Comment: @paj We don't have that module but we have Magento_Braintree module. I disabled the module before update but still facing same issue after Magento update.